# Synching check change event for two TreePanel in EXTJS 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, treepanel

I have two ExtJs TreePanel. One tree is fully loaded (call it FLTree) and second one is partially loaded (call it PL tree). When user clicks on a node in fully loaded tree & that node is present in partially loaded tree, I want to fire the checkchange event for that node in partially loaded tree.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: can you please look if the answer is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Ext.tree.Panel` has the `itemclick` event which is fired when an item is clicked (you need to add it in the controller or in the treepanel's listeners property.
The attributes are:

```
someFunctionName: function(treeview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) { ... }
```

From the record variable you can get the data needed from the first tree's selected node.

To find the other treepanel you can use the `up()` and `down()` methods on the treeview:

```
var parentContainer = treeview.up('container_xtype[someProperty1=someValue1]');
```

you can walk up in the component hierarchy (get that parent container which **contains both** treepanels).

```
var pLtree = parentContainer.down('treepanel[someProperty2=someValue2]');
```

If the two treepanel doesn't have common parent, then you can use the

```
var pLtree = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('treepanel[someProperty2=someValue2]')[0];
```

global method which returns an array of matched components. **BUT** make sure that you use a good component selector query (you can check if the returned array's length == 1).

Finally you need to use the `pLtree.fireEvent('checkchange', ...);` which is described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444541/firing-checkchange-event-on-a-tree-node-using-its-id-in-extjs-4-1).