# Firing checkchange event on a tree node using its ID in ExtJs 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a TreePanel. Each node in tree is given an ID. On click of a button, I want to fire the checkchange event for node 2.1 (as shown in the below tree). How can I fire checkchange event for a node using its ID on click of a button.

```
  1 
      1.2
      1.3
      1.4
  2
       2.1
       2.2
  3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fire the checkchange you need to have the node and if it's checked.

The `TreePanel` is using `Ext.data.TreeStore` to store it's nodes information (it is in the `store` property).

This TreeStore has the `getNodeById( id )` method which returns the record node by id.

If you want to get the node from another property, then you need to use the `tree` (`Ext.data.Tree`) property from `store`, which is like a node manager. This has a node record array in the `nodeHash` property. You need to iterate this Array and compare the given property manually.

The complete code:

```
buttonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var treepanel = button.up(...).down('treepanel');
        var node = treepanel.getStore().getNodeById(yourIDHere);
        // for custom property use this:
        /*var nodeHash = treepanel.getStore().tree.nodeHash;
        var node;
        for (var x in nodeHash) {
            if (nodeHash[x].get('customProperty') == customValue) {
                node = nodeHash[x];
                break;
            }
        } */
        treepanel.fireEvent('checkchange', node, node.get('checked'));
}
```